# Seleccion en tabla muchos a muchos MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, mvc

Hola gente estoy trabajando en mvc 5 model first y tengo 3 tablas.
-Roles
-RolesPermisos
-Permisos
al crear el mapeado de la base de datos EF no crea la tabla intermedia (RolesPermisos) como podria hacer una seleccion de la tabla "RolesPermisos" donde el rol = X en linq.
he probado con esto pero no me funciona

```
 var consulta = db.Roles.Include("Permisos").Where(x => x.IdRol == 24).Single();//me esta trayendo todos los rolesPermisos
```

Answer (score 0):

Intenta cambiarlo así a ver si te funciona:

```
var consulta = db.Roles.Where(x => x.IdRol == 24).Include("Permisos").FirstOrDefault();
```